# Connect colored dots - puzzle

Tags: visual, grid-deduction

This is a puzzle of connecting all same color dots with each other so all the dots can be connected together and no box can be empty.

The connections shouldnt be crossed with each other

Below is the puzzle photo,any help is appreciated[image: Connect the colored dots]

Comment: Hi! You may wish to indicate how far you've gotten and where you got stuck. That'll better enable people you precisely where you need it.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116586/four-pipes-on-a-8x8-grid

Comment: The "no box can be empty" rule turns out to be redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Note how the green flow must go around the light blue and yellow flows. Once you have the general path of the green flow, this puzzle is very easy.

Hint:

> General path only, not actual solution path.
>  [image]

Completed grid:

> [image]

Comment: As you drew it, connecting the blue dots necessarily disconnects the purple dots since the green line takes up the space around the turquoise dot.

Comment: @PattuX The blue path is strictly along the top and right edges.